# Edit the post title from the frontend

Tags: posts, slug, title, front-end

I have this form that allows-me to change some things of the current post in my frontend:

```
<form id="featured_upload" name="featured_upload" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><span class="badge badge-primary"><input type="file" name="my_image_upload" id="my_image_upload" multiple="false" required /></span></p>
<p><input type="text" name="newtags" id="newtags" value="" placeholder="new tags aqui..." /> <input type="text" name="h2" id="h2" value="" placeholder="h2 heading aqui..." /></p>
<p><input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="" /></p>
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'my_image_upload', 'my_image_upload_nonce' ); ?>
<span class="badge badge-light" ><input id="" name="" type="submit" value="Upload"/></span>
</form>
```

**Starting the saving process...**

```
// Check the nonce is valid, and the user can edit this post.
if ( isset( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], $_POST['post_id'] ) 
    && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], 'my_image_upload' )
    && current_user_can( 'manage_options', $_POST['post_id'] )) {
```

What I would like to do is to have the habitability of changing the post title (and slug also, of course...).

Can this be implemented on this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change post title and slug from frontend. by using `wp_update_post` you can change title and slug of post. in below code, it will update post title and slug of `post_id`. Replace `your-post-title-field` with your title field in form. slug will generated using that post title.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], $_POST['post_id'] ) 
    && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], 'my_image_upload' )
    && current_user_can( 'manage_options', $_POST['post_id'] )) {

    if(!empty($_POST['your-post-title-field']))
    {
      $new_slug = $new_title = sanitize_title($_POST['your-post-title-field']);
        wp_update_post(
            array (
                'ID'        => $_POST['post_id'],
                'post_title' => $new_title,
                'post_name' => $new_slug
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: in $_POST['post_id'] which id you get ?  you have to pass post id in value of name="post_id" which you want to update. currently it is blank that's why it is creating new post.

Comment: Thanks! Since my form submission is handling the current post, all I have to to was to remove `'ID' => $_POST['post_id'],`.